# Disable rsyslog remote server 's console messages

Tags: console, syslog

My console is been flooded with rsyslog messages. These are messages that come from a remote server:

```
   Message from syslogd@MSAN-RSPAE_O1A0F at Mar  3 11:07:13 ...
 rOT1[291]: 17/03/03 11:07:13 minor alarm occurred for service-id 703 mac-idx 17 (service affecting) : VPLS Duplicate MAC address, mac:00-A0-12-6F-4B-80,dup-port:ntio-1:sfp:7,dup-vlan:703,port:nta:xfp:1,vlan:703,cvlan:0,,
```

I'am trying to stop these messages to be printed to the console. Already tried changing the config file /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console
```

to

```
.*                                                      /dev/null
```

and restarting the rsyslogd after

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Already tried the:

```
sudo dmesg -n0
```

And until now, the messages keep appearing in the console of all users.

How to disable them once and for all?

Answer (score 7):

If you have the following line in your rsyslog.conf, you might consider commenting it out:

`*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*`

But you might also consider seeing if you can adjust the programme generating those logs, to avoid these being logged in the first.

Comment: commenting *.emerg fixed my issue.